# Why cant we lower temperature to X where if an electron is observed it will be as if its an unobserved Temperate Y

Tags: heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

Lets say the temperature is Y, and we want to observe an electron but if we do we will use a high energy light wave which will make it act more like a particle, so why dont we just lower the temperature to X where after the high energy light wave touches it, it would be like an un-observed electron at temperature Y

Was this already done or is there some reason we cant do it?